# Can I resume training a PyTorch model

Tags: pytorch

I haven't seen an example of this, but maybe I am googling the wrong terms...

Can I resume training a PyTorch model? For example,

1. I train for 20 epochs. The loss/accuracy graphs look good, so I would like to train another 30 epochs. Can I do this, or do I have to start over and do 50 epochs?
2. I train a model with 200 input images. I would now like to gather another 300 images and do further training with those 300 images. Can this be done, or do I have to start over with the 500 images?

Perhaps I can the previously saved training run and not clear the parameters?